# How to insert a JNE instruction (jump not equal) using buildmi in LLVM x86 machine function pass

Tags: assembly, x86, clang, llvm

I'm writing an LLVM machine function pass that need to insert some instructions at the start of each basic block. What those instructions do is that it load a value from a place and compare it with a number, then jump to a basic block if the previous comparison is not equal, thus I'm trying to insert a instruction `JNE` jump not equal, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my code

```cpp
void SomeFunction(llvm::MachineFunction &MF) {
        const TargetInstrInfo *TII = MF.getSubtarget().getInstrInfo();
//        MachineRegisterInfo &MRI = MF.getRegInfo();

        MachineBasicBlock *TrueBB = MF.CreateMachineBasicBlock();
        MF.insert(MF.end(),TrueBB);

        //      get the false basic block ready
//      this is stored at the end of the function that if in the previous block, if any of the jne actually jump into this block, it should terminate
        //                Location testing
        llvm::BuildMI(*TrueBB, TrueBB->begin(), TrueBB->begin()->getDebugLoc(), TII->get(X86::MOV64mr))
                .addReg(X86::RAX) // Base register for the destination address
                .addImm(1)        // Scale factor
                .addReg(0)        // Index register, none in this case
                .addImm(0)        // Displacement
                .addReg(0)        // Segment register, not used here
                .addImm(0);       // Immediate value to store
        llvm::BuildMI(*TrueBB, TrueBB->begin(), TrueBB->begin()->getDebugLoc(), TII->get(X86::MOV64ri), X86::RAX).addImm(0);
        llvm::BuildMI(*TrueBB, TrueBB->begin(), TrueBB->begin()->getDebugLoc(), TII->get(X86::NOOP));


//        then for other basic blocks that are not the first and last
        for (llvm::MachineFunction::iterator MBBItr = MF.begin(), MBBEnd = MF.end(); MBBItr != MBBEnd; MBBItr++){
            llvm::MachineBasicBlock &MBB = *MBBItr;
            if (&MBB != &MF.front() && &MBB != &MF.front()) {
                MachineBasicBlock::iterator FirstMI = MBB.begin();
                DebugLoc DL = FirstMI->getDebugLoc();

//                Location indicator for debug purpose
                BuildMI(MBB, FirstMI, DL, TII->get(X86::NOOP));
//              Both way works
//              Firstly load value from address stored in R14
//              addRegOffset(llvm::BuildMI(MBB, FirstMI, DL, TII->get(llvm::X86::MOV64rm),llvm::X86::RAX),
//                             llvm::X86::R14, false, 0);

                llvm::BuildMI(MBB, FirstMI, DL, TII->get(llvm::X86::MOV64rm),llvm::X86::RAX)
                    .addReg(llvm::X86::R14)
                    .addImm(1)
                    .addReg(llvm::X86::NoRegister)
                    .addImm(0)
                    .addReg(llvm::X86::NoRegister);

//              Then Compare it with our value
                llvm::BuildMI(MBB,FirstMI,DL,TII->get(llvm::X86::CMP64ri32))
                    .addReg(llvm::X86::RAX)
                    .addImm(0x11111111);

//              if the value isn't the same, means interrupt happened, jump to terminate block
//              This is the code that I couldn't get it to work
                llvm::BuildMI(MBB, FirstMI, DL, TII->get(llvm::X86::JCC_1))
                        .addImm(llvm::X86::COND_NE)
                        .addMBB(TrueBB);

            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

LLVM was successfully built, then when I try to compile some code, something like this shows up

```
# %bb.3:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB25_1 Depth=1
    nop
    movq    (%r14), %rax
    cmpq    $286331153, %rax                # imm = 0x11111111
    jo  5
```

It didn't compile into `JNE` but `JO`, not sure why it went wrong.
I understand that within a basic block, there shouldn't be any branching, it's for academic purpose so I just want to get it to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used LLVM's build machine instruction before but I am curious if this change makes a difference: `llvm::BuildMI(MBB, FirstMI, DL, TII->get(llvm::X86::JCC_1)).addMBB(TrueBB).addImm(llvm::X86::COND_NE);`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thanks Micheal for helping with the ordering. BuildMi do require things to be added in order. The other important thing is that I need to add `MBB.addSuccessor(TrueBB);` as you need to declare which block is the successor of the inserted block.